# Политика конфиденциальности Android

Tags: android

Есть ли пример политики конфиденциальности для Andorid, и можно сделать его просто локальным, не размещая эту страницу онлайн а просто на локальный файл

Answer (score 2):

Пишите privacy policy, выкладываете его куда-нибудь. Не обязательно иметь свой адрес, можно даже открыть какой-нить бесплатный блог(коих великое множество) и там выложить. Линк вставляете в Google developer console, разделе "Данные для Google Play" в самом низу. Все. Либо удаляете чувствительные permission если она не нужны в аппликации.

Comment: Ну не совсем, надо еще добавить документ в самом приложении

Comment: Что имеется ввиду добавить документ в само приложении, куда закинуть ссылку на эту политику конфедециальности.

Comment: А есть ли пример политики конфиденциальности для Andorid

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал ссылку на pdf файл на моем яндекс диске. Можно также сделать ссылку на файл типа Readme на github